# how to add element to json array within array?

Tags: typescript, angular7

here is my `array` below,

```
Array = [
0: {id: "1",Name:'Abc'}
1: {id: "2",Name:'Abc1'} 
2: {id: "3",Name:'Abc2'}
]
```

Now I want to add `{Country:'India'}` at position `Array[2]`, how can I achieve that.

Comment: `array[2].Country = 'India'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in javascript.

[image]

**UPDATE**

You can use `arr[2] = { County: "India" };` if you want to overwrite the element at position 2.

Comment: what if i want to add it to last position

Comment: What do you mean by last position ? You mean a new element in the array ?

Comment: Please check the update. You can use `arr[2] = { County: "India" };` to overwrite the element at position 2.

Answer (score 0):

to get the last postition just use this : array.length-1 as index of an array 
or you can specify your position by yourself .

```js
var arr = [{id: "1",Name:'Abc'},{id: "2",Name:'Abc1'} , {id: "3",Name:'Abc2'}];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
arr[arr.length-1].country = 'morocco';
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```